# Windows Chrome font-face rendering issue

Tags: windows, css, google-chrome, font-face

I have a font face on my site and the text comes out very rough on window chrome only.

I have done the following tweaks:
- made SVG first, tried adding a text shadow, tried antialiased font smoothing.

```
@font-face {
font-family:'grl';
src: url('../fonts/gotham-rounded-light_21020.eot');
src: url('../fonts/gotham-rounded-light_21020.eot?iefix') format('eot'), url('../fonts/gotham-rounded-light_21020.svg#webfontZam02nTh') format('svg'), url('../fonts/gotham-rounded-light_21020.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/gotham-rounded-light_21020.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-smooth: always;
}
```

here's the url 
http://thunder.beresponsive.net/meet-the-kids.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way currently to fix this. 
In some cases, adding CSS text-shadow helps. If it doesn't help, then you quite simply need to use a different font.

Google is aware of this issue, but they don't really care.

Comment: Such a pity considering they are web leaders

Comment: Yes, it is a pity. But try finding another half-decent webfont provider that gives out fonts for free. Not really out there. If you offer a free service, you're not bound by quality expectations. Simple. Just so you're aware, current chrome browsers do not recognise your last 2 css lines as valid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to specify the font-weight in a number value, i.e. `font-weight:200` rather than just "normal".